# Retrieve turple which contains array data in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have this types of tuple in database
[image]

How can I retrieve tuples where color includes 'green' ?

Comment: Anyone pls help

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
Model::where('color','like','%"green"%')->get();
```

or

```
Model::whereRaw('json_contains(color, \'["green"]\')')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from Laravel Doc! I can use `whereJsonContains()`!